# Persistence is at which layer?

Tags: http, tcp

I know that a http request first makes a 3 way handshake to establish connection. Followed by the request and response.

If a handshake is required for future requests then it is called non persistent connection.

The server can choose to keep the connection alive so that a handshake is not required untill a timeout value (persistent). This is called persistent connection. It saves time required by not requiring the 3 way handshake for each request.

My colleague mentions that http supports both persistent and non persistent. My understanding is that - tcp makes the connection. So persistence is controlled by tcp layer. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

May be not right. HTTP is higher layer than TCP and HTTP 1.0 will send `close()` when they finish tranportint some data streams. But in HTTP 1.1, the controller will not send `close()`, instead, it'll send keepalive/hearbeat to the other side for live. It is controlled by the application layer, in other words, by the HTTP itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way HTTP can support a persistent connection is called Server-Sent-Events.

An alternative to HTTP for persistant connections is WebSocket. WebSocket is a computer communications protocol, providing full-duplex communication channels over a single TCP connection. WebSocket enables streams of messages on top of TCP. WebSocket is distinct from HTTP.